# Знаки препинания "а(,) наоборот"

Tags: пунктуация

1) Это зачастую не приносит радости, а(,) наоборот(,) во многих ситуациях огорчает.

2) Это зачастую не приносит радости, а наоборот -- во многих ситуациях огорчает.

Какой из вариантов предпочтительнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "Это зачастую не приносит радости, а, наоборот, во многих ситуациях огорчает". Формально знаки препинания расставлены верно, но предложение "не читается" - интонационно оно не уравновешено. Кроме того, смысл неточен, так как "во многих ситуациях" находится не на месте (если "наоборот", то должно огорчать всегда,а не во многих ситуациях).
2. "Это зачастую не приносит радости, а наоборот - во многих ситуациях огорчает". Здесь интонация лучше, оборот "во многих ситуациях огорчает" имеет присоединительно-пояснительный характер и выделяется паузой и тире. Но смысловая неточность сохраняется.
3. Возможен вариант: "Это зачастую не приносит радости, а во многих ситуациях, наоборот, огорчает". Здесь, кажется, всё на месте (интонация и смысл).

Answer (score 0):

Вводное слово от союза "а" не отделяется запятой, если нарушается структура и смысл предложения. В первом варианте этого не происходит, поэтому он предпочтительнее. Второй вариант относится скорее к авторским, интонационным знакам препинания